# Excel IF(ISNUMBER clarification

Tags: excel-formula

Could somebody explain this formula to me,
- how does it work,
- and when to use it :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(D2),D2,IF(ISNUMBER(F2),F2,IF(ISNUMBER(H2),H2,"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It says if d2 is a number. Show d2 otherwise if f2 is. Number. Show f2. Else if h2 is a number. Show h2.

If none of them are numbers show a blank string

Comment: thanks very much for your help, another Q, how can i use if isblank to do the same job

Comment: Use not(isblank( g2 ) )